# Create a delegate of a generic function

Tags: .net, delegates, lambda, generic-function

I'm writing some unit tests and I have a lot of functions of the form

```
public void SomeTestHelperMethod<TKey, TValue>(TKey key, TValue value)
```

which I'm calling repeatedly with various arguments like this

```
SomeTestHelperMethod<int, int>(0, 1);
SomeTestHelperMethod<int, object>(1, new Nullable<double>(16.5));
SomeTestHelperMethod<int, string>(2, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
SomeTestHelperMethod<object, int>(new NullReferenceException(), 15);
SomeTestHelperMethod<object, object>(StringComparison.Ordinal, new Version());
SomeTestHelperMethod<object, string>((ushort)3, string.Empty);
SomeTestHelperMethod<string, int>(string.Empty, 195);
SomeTestHelperMethod<string, object>("A string", this);
SomeTestHelperMethod<string, string>("Another string", "Another string");
```

What I'd like to do is write a function that takes an Action delegate and can Invoke the delegate with all of the different arguments. Is there any way to do it?

**Answer:**

Thanks to MichaelCG here's what I ended up doing:

```
private void CallWithKeyAndValue(string methodName)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(ObservableDictionaryTest).GetMethod(methodName);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> kvp in ourKeyValueSet)
    {
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(kvp.Key.GetType(), kvp.Value.GetType());
        genericMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { kvp.Key, kvp.Value });
    }
}
```

I'd still be interested in a more general method but this one is functional for my purposes.

Comment: You mean so you can have a list of objects and just loop on it, but actually call the specific generic version of the method?

Comment: Something like that. Eventually I'd like to make some better test arguments than the random ones I made up and I'd like to be able to add it to all of the functions of this form in a single place. Right now I have a lot of duplicated code in my unit tests that I'd like to get rid of but the functions I'd like to call (SomeTestHelperMethod) are all generic functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should demonstrate what you are trying to do. The magic is in MakeGenericMethod.

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var meth = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Meth");
        var items = new[] { 
            new { a = (object)"hi", b = (object)1 },
            new { a = (object)TimeSpan.MaxValue, b = (object)DateTime.UtcNow },
        };
        foreach (var item in items) {
            var gmeth = meth.MakeGenericMethod(item.a.GetType(), item.b.GetType());
            gmeth.Invoke(null, new[] { item.a, item.b });
        }
    }

    public static void Meth<A, B>(A a, B b) {
        Console.WriteLine("<{0}, {1}>", typeof(A).Name, typeof(B).Name);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
<String, Int32> 
<TimeSpan, DateTime>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Beware if you ever overload `SomeTestHelperMethod` or make it non-public.

Comment: It's for unit tests so I don't think I'll ever care but that's good to know.

Comment: @Tinister, yea I always end up screwing up bindingflags so I figured I'd make the example really simple :).